# Move text in <header> element

Tags: html, css

So, I have a `<nav>` tag in `<header>` tag, but it is weirdly on the top, but I need it to be on the bottom.

Here is what I need it to look like:

[image]

And here it looks how it came out:

[image]

Here is the CSS code for the buttons and the header it is in.

```
#header {
    background-color: #886D75;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 0px;
}

#nav {
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
}
```

And here is the HTML.

```
    <header id="header">
        <img id="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="kasacast logo">
        <nav id="nav">
            <a href="home.html" id="home" class="nav">home&nbsp;</a>
            <a href="help.html" id="help" class="nav">help&nbsp;</a>
            <a href="https://app.tutturu.tv" id="tutturu" class="nav">tutturu&nbsp;</a>
            <a href="stream.html" id="stream" class="nav">stream&nbsp;</a>
            <a href="about.html" id="about" class="nav">about&nbsp;</a>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Comment: You can simply add ```margin-top``` to the class: nav

Answer (score 1):

Though there is already an answer here I am giving an easier solution. You can simply use `padding`:

```
#header {
    background-color: #886D75;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 0px;
    padding-top:10px; 
}

#nav {
    text-align: right;
    float: right;

}
```

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp

Answer (score 0):

If i do understand, this will do the trick.
Here some info about it: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```
header {
      width: 100%;
      height: 50px;
      background-color: red;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: flex-end;
    }
```

Comment: But the logo now is squished.

Comment: try:
`.logo { 
flex-shrink: 0;
}`
or give your logo a default width

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you need:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#header {
  background-image: url("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/75/2b/67/752b67b53f06b3707f133f8e81862ab8.jpg"); /* Use any image you need */
  background-repeat: none;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
}

#header #nav {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#header #nav #logo {
  width: 50px;
  height: auto;
}

#header #nav a {
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial; /* Change to whatever font you need */
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
    <header id="header">
        <nav id="nav">
            <!-- I'm just using a logo I have to load the image, replace it with your own again -->
            <img id="logo" src="https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/34989646?s=400&u=0bfacebf46980e16c03c3dfe62cc34e209be9e06&v=4" alt="kasacast logo"> 
            <div id="navitems">
                 <a href="home.html" id="home" class="nav">home&nbsp;</a>
                 <a href="help.html" id="help" class="nav">help&nbsp;</a>
                 <a href="https://app.tutturu.tv" id="tutturu" class="nav">tutturu&nbsp;</a>
                 <a href="stream.html" id="stream" class="nav">stream&nbsp;</a>
                 <a href="about.html" id="about" class="nav">about&nbsp;</a>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Comment: Hm, this one works well, but I need the logo to be approx. 10px from the left side, and I need to move the nav bar to the right, anyway how to do it?

Comment: @rixchy_ I have edited my answer to fit what you need. Also, I wouldn't recommend using `float: right` since float isn't meant for layouts. I've seen you have added `padding` top and right to get the position correct but do note that if you start to shrink your browser window, it won't be responsive (and will be hard to make responsive too)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it just by doing:

```
float: right;
padding-top: 18px;
padding-right: 20px;
```

It gave me the results I wanted.